# cant bind parameters to .net core

Tags: c#

getting nulls in the .net core method trying to send array of object.  I tried changing model but it won't seem to bind correctly

```
var dataObj = { OrderDetails: [] };
for (var i = 0; i < OrderUnits.length; i++) {
    if (OrderUnits[i].ProductID != null) {
        var DtoOrderDetails = {
            OrderID: OrderID,
            ProductID: OrderUnits[i].ProductID,
            Qty: OrderUnits[i].Quantity
        };
        dataObj.OrderDetails.push(DtoOrderDetails );
    }
}
if (dataObj.OrderDetails.length > 0) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).
```

and in .net core

```
   [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("AddOrderDetails")]
        public string AddOrderDetails([FromBody] AddOrderDetailsReq[] OrderDetails)


public class AddOrderDetailsReq
{
    public int? OrderID { get; set; }

    private int? ProductID { get; set; }

    private int? Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about exactly what "getting nulls" means, and where exactly in your code you're "getting" them? Do you have the code for `AddOrderDetails()`?

Comment: Check this out: https://kwilson.io/blog/post-an-array-of-objects-to-webapi-using-jquery/

Comment: Your action is taking an array, but you're passing it a single object containing an array. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var orderDetails = [];
for (var i = 0; i < OrderUnits.length; i++) {
    if (OrderUnits[i].ProductID != null) {
        var DtoOrderDetails = {
            OrderID: OrderID,
            ProductID: OrderUnits[i].ProductID,
            Qty: OrderUnits[i].Quantity
        };
        orderDetails.push(DtoOrderDetails );
    }
}
if (orderDetails.length > 0) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: JSON.stringify(orderDetails),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).
```